# MVC3 how to optimize the get and post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Just an introduction of my code...
I have a view that consists of
-details of an item
-questionnaire

The questionnaire part has:
-series of questions
-answer choices (can be single choice or multi-choice)

so in my viewmodel, I have like a mainviewmodel to contain the details of a certain item and inside that mainviewmodel, i have a property that maps to a questionnaireviewmodel.

questionnaireviewmodel:
- questionid
- answertype (single or multi-choice)
- answer_score
- answer_text

mainviewmodel:
- detailid
- name
- status
- questions : list

so in the view, i created a loop to display each of the questions and when a user click saves, it saves the answers to a database.

the problem..
The problem I have now is that its taking aorund 11secs to load the page and around 18 seconds to do the saving. Note that the questions count i have in my page is around 8 only. I noticed that my page size is sized around 630kb+ maybe because of the many hidden fields i have in my page to keep the details of the questions.

Do you have any suggestions quick or long term(rearchitecture) on how I can improve performance? I'm thinking of doing ajax call so as not to post the whole page on this but would love to hear your feedbacks. Thanks.

Comment: post a portion of the generated html.

Comment: Your 600Kb page... is counting all included JS/CSS or it is just the HTML?

Comment: @Nathan - when I try to paste the code, part of the code gets shown but the choices html code gets converted.. how do I paste code here? I tried enclosing with <code> tag but didn't work as only part of it gets pasted..

Comment: @Romias - css is not included and I have inline js in the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not easy to give you specific suggestions on rearchitecture before analyzing the whole application and reviewing the whole source code. My recommendation is doing profiling. Justly click VisualStudio2010 menu 'Aanlyze'-'Launch performance wizard'. Start you application in release mode and record your actions. Finally the profiling report will tell you the hot lines that takes most time of 11s. Hope this helps.